# Setup virtualhost for symfony project in apache in doker container

Tags: docker, apache, symfony

I'm trying to setup a `sympony 3.4` project in docker using apache, but it doesn't work, the werser works  but no t with the symfony project

this is the Dockerfile

```
FROM php:7.4.2-apache

RUN pecl install xdebug && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug \
# not yet in linux: xdebug.remote_host = host.docker.internal \n\
&& echo "\n\
xdebug.mode = debug \n\
xdebug.start_with_request = yes \n\
xdebug.client_port = 9003 \n\
xdebug.client_host = host.docker.internal \n\
xdebug.log = "C:\xdebug_log\xdebug.log" \n\
xdebug.idekey = VSCODE \n\
" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini
```

and the `dockercompose.yml`

```
version: "3.7"

services:

    apache_with_php:
        build: .
        container_name: php74_apache
        volumes:
            - ./:/var/www/html/
        ports:
            - "80:80"
    memcached:
        image: memcached:alpine
        container_name: memcached

    mailhog:
        image: mailhog/mailhog:latest
        container_name: mailhog
        ports:
          - "1026:8025"

    redis:
        image: redis:alpine
        container_name: redis

    mariadb:
        image: mariadb:10.4
        container_name: mariadb
        working_dir: /application
        volumes:
          - .:/application
        environment:
          - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=mypass
          - MYSQL_DATABASE=mydb
          - MYSQL_USER=myuser
          - MYSQL_PASSWORD=mypass
        ports:
          - "1028:3306"
```

How I could set a virtual host inside the docker container?

Comment: you might find it easier to use Lando that will build the docker containers including apache, mysql and will even give you a virtual domain to use. Works on both Windows and Mac. https://lando.dev/

Comment: What **exactly** is not working? What have you tried to make it work? I don't see any obvious problems with the configuration